# Remove "Home page" title from home page

Tags: frontend

On my startpage is a bold headline: **Home page**

How can I remove it?

[image: Magento Home Page]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](https://snag.gy/drLEy.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: Additional clarity would have been better. There are multiple ways to remove this text. Your solution is one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in `CMS > Pages` and open `Home page`. On the left click "Content". Here you can remove the text.

Comment: this is the reason you got downvote. btw, i have not ;)

Comment: Really? Looks like people here are not used to the Stackoverflow System. If you ask a question there is a checkbox: `Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style`. This is explicitly encouraged. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Oops.. You went on a wrong track. It's always good to answer your own question and accept it if you don't find one. You may got downvotes because of the sheer simple thing which you could have easily identified. Downvote means - `This question does not show any research effort`

Comment: Yeah, that could be it. I wrote the research in the answer. True, it's a really simple question...

Comment: [Pim Schaaf](http://magento.stackexchange.com/users/31869/pim-schaaf) Thanks for the [edit](http://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/59519). I don't see why it was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP discovered this text is the default content of the CMS Page for the home page. You can totally remove that "Home Page" text and any CMS defined there by adding a section to your local.xml file

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/layout/local.xml
```

Add this XML:

```
 <cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
       <remove name="cms_page" />
       ...
    </reference>
 </cms_index_index>
```

If you don't want to have a completely blank page :) you can enter in some other blocks within that reference.

I find it useful to put as much of the design work into the XML and templates and avoid using the CMS for page structure - leave that for static blocks of text that the site admin may want to change once it goes live.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code inside your `cms_index_index.xml`:

```
<referenceBlock name="cms_page" remove="true" />
```